# how to automatically perform a function on a html element when it added in dom by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events, dom

I want to perform a action on a html element with a specific class automatically when it added in DOM ,

Ex :-

```
<html>

  <head>

       <script type="text/javascript "src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                 $('.hlo').attr('new', 'false'); 

            });

       </script>

  </head>

  <body>

      <span class="hlo"> blah blah </span>
      <span class="hlo"> blah blah </span>

  </body> 


</html>
```

this works fine, it add a attribute to all html elements that has "hlo" class but the problem is once i load more data by ajax ( or other way ) , it does not work,

i know i can do like this :-

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '/blah',
             success: function(data){

                 $('body').append(data);   // think data = <span class="hlo"> </span>
                 $('.hlo').attr('new', 'false'); 

            }
});
```

but i don't want that ,,  what i want is done by some jquery plugins for their use, for example when we use some scroll plugin like this :-

```
$('.my_select').custom_scroll();
```

and then it works automatically, ex:

when i will write like this -

```
<div class=".my_select">  

    <div class="inner">

          // data with custom scroll

    </div>

</div>
```

so that plugins automatically change this to like this :-

```
<div class="ss">

    <div class="ss_content">

           // now data with a custom scroll bar 

    </div>    

    <div class="scroll_bar_holder">

       <div class="scroll_bar"> </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

that's what i want to do, actually i want to do this-

```
 <div class="tt">  hello world :)   </div>
```

when this added to page, it should be automatically convert to

```
 <div class="tt"> hello world <img src="smile_emo.png"> </div>
```

mean automatically change some symbals with images or emotions for html elements with a particuler class

so how i can acheive that ? Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: In Success did you appended data to body and processed your script ?

Comment: edited ,, and i said i don't want to do that ,, i want the method that used by some scroll plugin i also explained that in question :(

Comment: If your logic is to add image inside div, you can write that with custom scripts and there is no use of scroll like plugins

Comment: just want to say, I guess the class name in your dom should not have the dot ?
<div class=".tt">   --> <div class="tt">

Answer (score 1):

use can use code like below. use  [ajaxcomplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)  which fires when any ajax call completed on page. so in this case you don't need to put some common code inside each ajax success function

**Note : i post my answer base on your first example in question**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if ( settings.url === "/blah" ) {
       $('.hlo').attr('new', 'false');
       $('.tt').each(function(){
          if($(this).text().indexOf(':)') >= 0){
             $(this).text($(this).text().replace(':)','<img src="smile_emo.png">'));
          }
       });  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: => i load more data by ajax ( or other way ), the other way is actually iframe  :)  ,,  iframe code look this this-  <script type="text/javascript"> parent.boot.dt_ar({ "__html" : "<span class'hlo'> </sapn>"); </script>

Comment: then boot.dt_ar = function(obj){   $('body').append(obj.__html);  }  ,, something

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating the elements dynamically you can pre-format their content using .replace() JavaScript function. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>     
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addNew').on('click', addNewElem);
});

function addNewElem() {
    var $newElem = $("<div> [no] do not do that! [yes] that is right! [smile]</div>"),
        smileys = {
            "[no]" : '<img src="http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-basic/happyno.gif">',
            "[smile]" : '<img src="http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-basic/baloon.gif" >',
            "[yes]" : '<img src="http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-basic/happyyes.gif" >'
        };
    $.each(smileys, function(i,e){        
        var text = $newElem.html().replace(i,e);        
        $newElem.empty().html(text).appendTo('.container');
    });
} 
</script>        
</head>
<body>
  <button id="addNew">Add New Element</button>
  <div class="container"></div>      
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/7jo13n0L/)

Comment: [quote]mean automatically change some symbals with images or emotions for html elements with a particuler class, so how i can acheive that ?[/quote] - was not that your question? The addNewElem function is an example. You should give some though on that.